# PHP Fatal Error when searching a query that returns no results (Woocommerce Blank page of death)

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce shop where the archive-products.php template comes up blank (only loads the header) whenever I search a query I know will return no results.

I turned the log on and came up with these two lines:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php on line 249

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3854336 bytes) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4344

I replicated it multiple times and it throws the same error all the time, besides one time that the error came up as:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 155648 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

On my development enviroment these files are the same, but the error only happens on my production enviroment , so I am wondering if this is actually a memory issue or maybe something else, has anyone come up with this issue before?

UPDATE:

So I narrowed the issue down to the call of wc_get_template( ) inside of wc_no_products_found() , im not sure how it works but it seems to be having issues when trying to call the no-products-found.php file (which does exist on the woocommerce plugin folder)

Answer (score 0):

edit your PHP.ini file. Simply increase the default value

find and change this

```
  memory_limit = 128M
```

to

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

now it should work

Comment: and yes it's a memory issue default value is 128M just increase it to 256M or 1024 depend on you RAM